# Unable to determine application id: com.android.tools.idea.run.ApkProvisionException

Tags: android

When I try run my Android application after upgrading Android Studio, I get this error

'Unable to determine application id: com.android.tools.idea.run.ApkProvisionException: No outputs for the main artifact of variant: debug'

I tried in run/debug configuration change deploy to 'Nothing' then I get error for some class doesn't exist.

This is my build.gradle file, please look at it and tell me what is your opinions.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
def AAVersion = '4.0.0'

dependencies {
   apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
   compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
}

apt {
  arguments {
    androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile

    resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.applicationId

 }
}


android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "bg.isic.myisicapp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 25
    versionName "1.4.5"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFile 'proguard-android-annotations.pro'
        proguardFile 'proguard-android-gif-drawable.pro'
        proguardFile 'proguard-eventbus.pro'
        proguardFile 'proguard-gson.pro'
        proguardFile 'proguard-guava.pro'
        proguardFile 'proguard-retrofit.pro'
        proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
        proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    }
  }
 }

dependencies {
  compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.3'
  compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.0.2'
  compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
  compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:layouts:0.4.2'
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
  compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
  compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
  compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
  compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
  compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
  compile 'rongi.rotate-layout:rotate-layout:2.0.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
  compile('com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.1') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4';
    exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.9'
apt 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.9'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
dependencies {
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
 }
```

Anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the proper Android Gradle Plugin version for the Android Studio version you are using.

I encountered this after updating Android Studio. I don't know if this was your issue or not, but in case others are seeing it here's what I found had happened.

1. I updated Android Studio
2. I either missed or dismissed the "update android gradle plugin", and no gradle sync seemed to happen
3. When building everything would be fine, but then fail to find my output file

To resolve I had to simply force a gradle sync, at which point Android studio saw I had an old Android Gradle Plugin version for the current Android Studio version and prompted me to update.

Answer (score 0):

I find this error when i update my android studio to 4.1.1
then i update my gradle verstion from 6.7.0 to 6.7.1,  it is solved by this way.